# BasicDataSource vs DriverManagerDataSource. Which is better for production ready spring-hibernate application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, datasource, connection-pooling

There are many DataSource implementation classes are available like `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource`, `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource`. How can I decide(chose) which one to use in my **Spring-mvc + Hibernate** application?

Comment: Spring Boot uses the Hikari connection pool by default. It's a very good and efficient pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go through [Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html)

> DriverManagerDataSource: This class is not an actual connection pool; it does not actually pool
>   Connections. It just serves as simple replacement for a full-blown
>   connection pool, implementing the same standard interface, but
>   creating new Connections on every call.
>
> Useful for test or standalone environments

On other hand DBCP's BasicDataSource provide "real" connection pool outside of a J2EE container. Commons DBCP's BasicDataSource and C3P0's ComboPooledDataSource are full connection pool beans, supporting the same basic properties as this class plus specific settings (such as min/max pool size etc).

So if you are developing a test application then `DriverManagerDataSource` is okay but for production ready applications must go with "real" connection pool i.e C3p0's `ComboPooledDataSource` or DBCP's `BasicDataSource`.

***Ref:*** https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch12s03.html